# circular permutation in case of identical diamond and pearls

Tags: permutations

***the number of ways a necklace can be formed by 18 identical diamond and 3 identical pearl ?***
 **my solution is that**
 divide the procedure into three case **case1**:all  pearls together that leads to only one case. **case 2**: two pearls together and one seperate that leads to  9 cases  and last **case 3** all seperate :which i am unable to do plzz help  and

> ANWSER  IS 37

Comment: Are you familiar with multinomials?

Comment: yes little bit you can try answering me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made a good start. Now you need to list the possibilities for the number of diamonds in the three groups in case 3. You need three positive integers totalling 18. So you have: 18=16+1+1, 15+2+1, 14+3+1, 14+2+2, 13+4+1, 13+3+2, 12+5+1, 12+4+2, 12+3+3 and so on down through 9+8+1 ... 8+8+2 ... 7+7+4 ... 6+6+6. You will find there are 27 of them. Each one gives just one necklace. Add them to the 10 you have already.

Comment: is there any other way instead of counting 27 possibilities